# Gcloud app deploy failing with mongo-driver because of DataDog/zstd

Tags: mongodb, go

I have been using mongo-driver in my project, deploying with gcloud app deploy for a while now. I recently rebuild my machine, and simply ran **go get** to get fetch ally my dependencies. Everything is compiling fine locally, however, **gcloud app deploy** fails:

```
    Failed to build app: building app with command '[go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start ***\admin]', env '[PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=***HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GOPATH=/tmp/staging/srv/gopath]': err=exit status 1, out=srv/gopath/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/compression_cgo.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/DataDog/zstd" in any of:
    /tmp/staging/srv/gopath/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/vendor/github.com/DataDog/zstd (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/DataDog/zstd (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/staging/srv/gopath/src/github.com/DataDog/zstd (from $GOPATH).
```

Any ideas? app.yaml is just **runtime: go113**

Comment: Which version of `mongo-go-driver` ? Which version of Go ? Could you do a normal go build to test without the `gcloud` ? What's your operating system ? Cheers.

Comment: **go build** runs fine,and **go run main.go** starts the app, and all works fine locally. **go version go1.13.3** (I've tried it on both linux and windows, with the same result). No Idea on the driver version...whatever you get when you run **go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying dependencies with **go mod** yet?
I faced the same issue and finally can solved by generating **go.mod** file with these command,

```
GO111MODULE=on go mod init

GO111MODULE=on go mod tidy
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go) is the details explanation.